# Limit posts to current category in shortcode

Tags: wordpress, loops, categories, shortcode

I have a custom shortcode to be used on archive pages and list the first 3 posts. But how do I limit the posts displayed to the current category without hardcoding categories?

This is working, but shows posts from all categories.

```
function archive_loop_shortcode() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_query($args);
if($my_query->have_posts()):
    while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $custom = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
    echo "<div>".get_the_post_thumbnail()."</div>";
        echo "<h3>".get_the_title()."</h3>";
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'archive_loop', 'archive_loop_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps,

```
function archive_loop_shortcode() {
    $current_cat = get_queried_object();
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $current_cat->taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $current_cat->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_query( $args );
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ):
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
            $custom = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
            echo "<div>" . get_the_post_thumbnail() . "</div>";
            echo "<h3>" . get_the_title() . "</h3>";
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
    endif;
}

add_shortcode( 'archive_loop', 'archive_loop_shortcode' );
```